# usage of tmpfile() in C

Tags: c, stdio, temporary-files

I don't understand why my script below seems to work without creating any files.

script.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("P_tmpdir is '%s'\n", P_tmpdir);
    FILE *tmp = tmpfile();
    if(tmp == NULL){
        printf("Unable to create temp file");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("Temporary file is created\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'){
        fputc(string[i], tmp);
    }
    rewind(tmp);
    while(!feof(tmp)){
        putchar(fgetc(tmp));
    }
    sleep(3);
    return(0);
}
```

The P_tmpdir variable returns me the "/tmp" directory although in the sleeping time no new file is created in it... can you help me or explain me plz ?

Comment: fighting a losing battle against calling c code 'scripts'

Comment: Posted code does not compile.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).

Comment: @pm100: Closing the file would cause it to be removed from the file system. C 2018 7.21.4.3 2 says “The `tmpfile` function creates a temporary binary file that is different from any other existing file and that will automatically be removed when it is closed or at program termination…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil so the only way to read it back is via rewind - like here. (I misread the man page)

Comment: I assume fflush would force the file to be written

Comment: You might see the name if you use iNotify to detect changes in `/tmp`.  You might get bored by the amount of activity in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile) (emphasis mine):

> On some implementations (e.g. Linux), this function actually creates, opens, and **immediately** deletes the file from the file system: as long as an open file descriptor to a deleted file is held by a program, the file exists, but since it was deleted, **its name does not appear in any directory**, so that no other process can open it.

The file does not have to be "visible" in the file system tree, as long as a process has a handle on it, the file continues to exist.

If you want a file that's visible in the file system tree you should use [mkstemp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html).

Comment: this is a common pattern on Linux, for example most terminals that are configured to have infinite scrolling history will create a file for backing up the screen data and unlink it immediately

Comment: @phuclv I'm assuming one could still open the file via `/proc/[pid]/fd/[fd]` right?

Comment: probably. The point is to automatically clear the current session when the terminal crashes or exits, not to hide the file from anyone

Comment: @phuclv That's actually pretty smart, cleaning up temporary files is always a pain

Comment: Though we know nothing about the OP platform, because didn't bothered to tell.. on glibc at least tmpfile() opens a O_TMPFILE|O_EXCL fd that is never materialized on the filesystem and no matter what happens the kernel will destroy it when the program terminates. (old versions use the racy create and unlink trick though)